# extracting value of unordered list list item value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Dear all I have used the below codes to extract the value of `<li>` in which image is displayed horizontally. The HTML code is as

```
<div id="layoutInnerOptions">
<ul id="navigationItemsContainer" class="layouts_list">
<li class="layout_container" rel="0" value="temp1">
<img src="resources/Images/layout_bottom2.png" alt="bottom" rel="0" />
</li>
<li class="layout_container" rel="1" value="temp4">
<img src="resources/Images/layout_top2.png" alt="top" rel="1" />
</li>
<li class="layout_container" rel="2" value="temp3">
<img src="resources/Images/layout_menu2.png" alt="menu" rel="2" />
<li class="layout_container" rel="3" value="temp2">
<img src="resources/Images/layout_buttons2.png" alt="buttons" rel="3" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have used jQuery to get the value of `<li>` like temp1,temp2 but could not get the value by using the below code.

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?')==true) {
   var Apptxt = $("#AppNametxt").val();
   var Appdesc=$("#txtdesc").val();
   var Applayout=$("#navigationItemsContainer").val();
   $.post("http://www.domain_name.com/data.php",{Starts:'appcontent', Appdesc:Appdesc, Apptxt:Apptxt, Applayout:Applayout},        
      function(data) {
    $('#message').html("Content Saved");
  });
}
```

I hope that you all will help to solve this problem.
Thank you all.

Comment: We use `.val()` for form elements only and `.text()` or `.html()` for container elements that are of the form `<element>SomeText/SomeHTML</element>`

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by value of `<li>`?

Comment: I need to get the value of <li> i.e. temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4 as I click the respective list image. The above values are as <li value="temp1"> I need this value to store in the database.

Comment: Just remember that the value attribute is reserved for form elements. I would advise that you use a data-value attribute instead: `<li data-value="temp1">`. When you target `#navigationItemsContainer` do you want to get the data from all `<li>` elements? You do not have `#AppNametxt` and `#txtdesc`, so what are you targeting here?

Comment: I used <li data-value="temp1"> this but it's giving only a single value i.e. temp1 only, it doesn't provide me other respective value which is associated with it when the other image is clicked. I have already extracted the value of #AppNametxt and #txtdesc but could not extract the value of #navigationItemsContainer unordered list item value.

Comment: See my answer and demo below.

Comment: I viewed the demo and tested at my site too and thankx for it but the requirement is when the list item image is clicked it should send it's respective value to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `value=...` to `data-value=....` and use code similar to that below:

```
var Applayout= $("#navigationItemsContainer").find('li').map(function() { return $(this).data('value'); }).get().join(',');
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/95ahC/)

**EDIT**

User has changed his requirements to include a trigger - a click of the li item - which changes the code to the following:

```
$(function() {
   $("#navigationItemsContainer").children( 'li' ).on( 'click', function() {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?')) {
         var Apptxt = .....;
         var Appdesc = ......;
         var Applayout = $( this ).data( 'value' );
         $.post("http://www.domain_name.com/data.php",{Starts:'appcontent', Appdesc:Appdesc, Apptxt:Apptxt, Applayout:Applayout}, function(data) {
            $('#message').html("Content Saved");
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: sir this list has got individual links and want to get the value when the individual list item is clicked it's respective value should be stored within the variable. Thank you for extracting all the list values but the requirement is as noted above.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear at all. By giving us `var Applayout= $("#navigationItemsContainer").val()` you indicated that you wanted to get the data from all children of this ul element. Please clarify what variable should carry data for each.

Comment: Please see updated code above. Let me know if there's a problem.